# Haskell -- suppress import errors

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I have a bunch of Haskell files I need to compile with GHC, but some import libraries that don't exist. Is there a way to suppress the compiler error: `Could not find module`, and only make it throw during runtime? Something like `-fdefer-type-errors` does, but for imports.

Editing the files is not an option at the moment, and most imports are not even used by the program, so would never throw if it compiled.

Comment: You can define functions as `undefined` in the top of your file as a "placeholder". So if you need a function `foo` write `foo = undefined`. Use `foo` everywhere were that is needed. If you later can import `foo`, then you can remove the `foo = undefined` error.

Comment: It's not quite feasible to create an empty library for each of those bogus imports, as there's many different ones

Comment: but you don't need to create an empty library. You simply put placeholders in the module where you *use* that function.

Comment: There is [`-fdefer-out-of-scope-variables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--fdefer-out-of-scope-variables), but then you'll still have to comment out the import statements.

Comment: I never even use those functions, so the only problem is the actual import statement. However, it's not straight forward for me to edit the files themselves, so I'm looking at a workaround to make the error into a warning or something like that

Comment: You import a module, but never use anything from it? Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cabal's `mixins` to expose other, existing, modules with the names of the modules you desire to exist. For example you might have a file:

```
module MyLib (someFunc) where

import Module1
import Module2

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"
```

So `Module1` and `Module2` do not actually exist.  But you can point those modules to anything, such as `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` using the cabal file:

```
library
    exposed-modules:  MyLib

    -- Modules included in this library but not exported.
    -- other-modules:

    -- LANGUAGE extensions used by modules in this package.
    -- other-extensions:
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.0.0, containers
    hs-source-dirs:   src
    default-language: Haskell2010
    mixins:
        containers (Data.Map as Module1, Data.Set as Module2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in GHC that allows compilation when an imported module can not be found.